# Not able to open default webpage in webview

Tags: android, tabs, webview, default

I am new to android development,
I have an application with a webview. This webview is inside my tablayout's framelayout. My tabs are showing up webpages proerly but but my default tab is displaying a blank screen. Here is my code which is implemented. Please help me to fix this problem.

```
private WebView webview;
private TabHost mTabHost;

public class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
   public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mTabHost = getTabHost();

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_featured").setIndicator("Featured", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.featured_selected)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_recent").setIndicator("recent", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.recent_selected)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_playlist").setIndicator("playlist", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.playlist_selected)).setContent(R.id.webview));
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_search").setIndicator("search", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.search_selected)).setContent(R.id.webview));

    mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

    webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

    webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);

    mTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if(tabId.equals("tab_featured")){
                webview.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
            }else if(tabId.equals("tab_recent")){
                webview.loadUrl("http://www.useit.com");
            }else if(tabId.equals("tab_playlist")){
                webview.loadUrl("http://www.flipkart.com");
            }else if(tabId.equals("tab_search")){
                webview.loadUrl("http://www.hotmail.com");
            }
        }  
    } );
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you debug the code and see if it is getting into the if's

Comment: yeah i did, see what is happening is ... when i start the application i have a default tab which is selected by default but the webview in its framelayout is showing a blank page. But when i switch to other tabs and also back to my default tab they show corresponding webpages properly. So i just wanted to know how to load a default page in the default selected tab. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Move

```
webview.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

after this line

```
webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
```